# Swipe to Pop Page JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, onsen-ui

With the new development tools, such as the Onsen CSS Components (http://onsenui.io), theming web apps to look native is becoming a reality.

The last part of completing this task, is to allow the user to swipe left, as they would with a native app, to go to the previous page.

Does anyone know of a way (probably through js) that the user could swipe to the left, and the screen would pop, back, following the motion of their finger? (Similar to iOS 7)

Answer (score 0):

You can detect swipe left/right using ngTouch.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch

Comment: How often can it refresh the position of the input device?